# first java program is not working

Tags: java

I'm new in `Java`, it's my first attempt to write a program:
I need to write a program that prints the sum of all positive integers smaller
  than 1000, that are divided by either 3 or 5.
Here is my (poorly) attempt. after compiling it is just receiving numbers and showing them :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num=1;
        int count = 1;
        while (count <=1000) {
            if (count%3==0|count%5==0){
                count = count+num;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: `count = count+num;` kind of seems wrong for what `count` "seems" to be used for

Comment: You seem to be using `count` for two purposes - this won't work. You first line should be `num += count`.

Comment: *"first java program is not working"* - Congratulations, you have your first bug! :-)

Comment: I think I have reached my "1000th java program not working"

Answer (score 3):

Given you used a while, I assume you don't know about for loops, so I'll avoid using it.

Your code should:

1. Your initial sum, before any number, is 0
2. Iterate (i.e. go through the values) the values from 1 to 1000
3. If the value is divisible by 3 or 5, add it to a sum.
4. Print the sum.

Point 1):

```
int sum = 0;
```

Point 2):

```
int value = 1;
while (value <= 1000) {
   //do point 3
   value++;
}
```

Point 3):

```
if ((value%3==0) || (value%5==0)) {
  sum = sum + value;
}
```

Point 4):

```
System.out.println(sum);
```

Putting it all together:

```
int sum = 0;
int value = 1;
while (value <= 1000) {
  if ((value%3==0) || (value%5==0)) {
    sum = sum + value;
  }
  value++;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Your main error is in using count both for the sum and for the value check of the while condition. The misusage of the single pipe as or is also a mistake.

Hope this helps

Comment: In fact, the use of `|` instead of `||` makes no practical difference here.  It is at worse a "stylistic mistake".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
            int num=1;
            int sum=0;
            while (num <=1000) {
                if (num%3==0||num%5==0){
                    sum = sum +num;
                }
                num++;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea great.  How about explaining what the problem was?  In words?

Answer (score 0):

You have put your `count++` inside if block. That means if the number is divisible by 3 or 5 then you are incrementing the `count` . Place it outside of your if block. I have re-write your code as follows -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ex1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 1;

        while (count <=1000) {
            if (count%3==0||count%5==0){
                sum = sum + count;
            }
            count++;

        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```